# How to react to a malformed Accept-Language header?

Tags: http, header, http-status-code-400, malformed, http-accept-language

How should a server react to a malformed `Accept-Language` header that doesn't conform to RFC 9110? Should it return a 400 Bad Request or should it ignore the header?

I would tend to return a 400 error, but since it is just a preference, maybe it should be handled more gracefully. Does it make a difference if the request is for a web page from a browser or to an Open API endpoint? I couldn't find any information.

Comment: Here's one relevant discussion, including top-5 Alexa sites behaviour: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/2097. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) suggests to ignore unsupported header value or return a 406 response if this is extremely important. I'd ignore such error.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Then I will ignore the response. You can add it as an answer then I can accept it.